# Is it correct if I reply starting with - "Will"

Tags: expressions

I don't know, but sometimes, For example if someone said to you "Okay we will meet tomorrow". Is it correct if I reply, "Will see you soon". Is it necessary to add "I"? like "I will...". Hope you guys are getting me.

Comment: Are you talking about a formal reply to the Queen or a text message to your buddy?

Comment: In the txt msg to your buddy context, "Will see you" is acceptable, like "Will do"; however, neither one is "correct"-they are simply customary fragments, and the listener must assume their subjects.

Comment: In an informal context 'See you soon' is more usual, at least where I come from.